# Which format Alinea sol report module use to store report fields in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

we use alinea sol plugin to generate report in our sugarcrm. In database, asol_reports table in report_fields column, alinea sol store report fields definition in base64 encoded text. So, I decoded that, i get this result

```
"a:2:{s:6:"tables";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"data";a:3:{i:0;a:17:{s:5:"field";s:10:"account_id";s:5:"alias";s:12:"Account Name";s:14:"fieldReference";s:10:"account_id";s:7:"visible";s:3:"yes";s:13:"sortDirection";s:1:"0";s:9:"sortOrder";s:0:"";s:8:"function";s:1:"0";s:3:"sql";s:0:"";s:6:"format";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:0:"";}s:8:"grouping";s:7:"Grouped";s:13:"groupingOrder";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:6:"relate";s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:9:"isRelated";b:0;s:5:"index";s:3:"0_1";s:12:"enumOperator";s:0:"";s:13:"enumReference";s:0:"";}i:1;a:17:{s:5:"field";s:11:"case_number";s:5:"alias";s:6:"Number";s:14:"fieldReference";s:11:"case_number";s:7:"visible";s:3:"yes";s:13:"sortDirection";s:1:"0";s:9:"sortOrder";s:0:"";s:8:"function";s:1:"0";s:3:"sql";s:0:"";s:6:"format";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:0:"";}s:8:"grouping";s:1:"0";s:13:"groupingOrder";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:9:"isRelated";b:0;s:5:"index";s:3:"1_1";s:12:"enumOperator";s:0:"";s:13:"enumReference";s:0:"";}i:2;a:17:{s:5:"field";s:11:"description";s:5:"alias";s:11:"Description";s:14:"fieldReference";s:11:"description";s:7:"visible";s:3:"yes";s:13:"sortDirection";s:1:"0";s:9:"sortOrder";s:0:"";s:8:"function";s:1:"0";s:3:"sql";s:0:"";s:6:"format";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:0:"";}s:8:"grouping";s:1:"0";s:13:"groupingOrder";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:9:"isRelated";b:0;s:5:"index";s:3:"2_1";s:12:"enumOperator";s:0:"";s:13:"enumReference";s:0:"";}}s:6:"config";a:10:{s:7:"visible";b:1;s:10:"multiQuery";b:0;s:12:"deletedUsage";b:0;s:15:"paginationUsage";b:0;s:17:"paginationEntries";s:0:"";s:6:"titles";a:1:{s:7:"visible";b:1;}s:7:"headers";a:1:{s:7:"visible";b:1;}s:9:"subtotals";a:1:{s:7:"visible";b:1;}s:6:"totals";a:1:{s:7:"visible";b:1;}s:10:"pagination";a:1:{s:7:"visible";s:3:"all";}}}}s:7:"version";s:5:"5.0.2";}"
```

At first, I thought that this is in JSON. But later, I got that it is not in JSON. So, kindly help me to know in which format asol stores fields definition in asol_reports table. Also, if possible, kindly guide me to read this so programmatically I can fetch field names from this result. Thank you in advance